# timing issue with detecting window.innerHeight

Tags: javascript

I have a page that I open as a popup using window.open from another page; at this point the `window.open` call specifies a given height and width for the popup page.

In the popup page I detect the available screen size using `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth` (and similar for crossbrowser compatibility).

```
window.onload = function() { 
   if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) { 
      ww = window.innerWidth; wh = window.innerHeight; 
   } `
```

This sometimes fails to work if the popup is openend using this:

```
newHeight = 400; 
newWidth = 400; 
window.open("popup.html", "", "height=" + newHeight + ",width=" + newWidth);
```

The issue I'm having is that I have sometimes timing issues with the height/width detection; under some circumstances, the height/width returned are not the ones the popup window has been set to, but some other values (it looks like the values of the opener window).

It looks like the `window.innerHeight` is detected before the height/width settings of the popup window are enforced.

Normally, in the popup I detect height and width within a `window.onload` function.
I believe this might be a timing issue because the issue disappears if I add a timeout delay of 30ms, with a shorter delay the issue might still happen.

Question: is there an event in the opened window that ensures me that the height/width settings of the openers' `window.open` have been applied?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the `load` event fires off before truly loading everything (such as font-face declarations), try with...

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
     var ww = window.innerWidth; 
     var wh = window.innerHeight;
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand your answer. Where am I supposed to use calculateWindowDimensions?

Comment: Each time you open a pop-up you calculate the window dimensions, instead of caculating it on window.onload. Post your current code if you need tailored answers.

Comment: In my popup:

`
window.onload = function() {
  ...
  if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) { ww = window.innerWidth; wh = window.innerHeight; }
`

This sometimes fails to work if the popup is openend using this:

`
newHeight = 400;
newWidth = 400;
window.open("popup.html", "", "height=" + newHeight + ",width=" + newWidth);
`

The issue is, sometimes I have timing issue with the popup onload function detecting the wrong dimentions, s if the window did not apply yet the height= and width= settings from window.open.

Comment: In the future edit your question and post the code there, I've already done this for you, StackOverflow is kinda like a wiki in this matter. I've updated my answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However it looks like a bug of google chrome, I isolated an example that fails with chrome and works with everyone else. See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=154559 (using onreadystatechange also fails with chrome).