# window.innerHeight takes approx 150ms to update after requestFullscreen(). What's the best way to deal with this?

Tags: javascript, html, api, fullscreen

[image: 10 trials of window.innerHeight after requestFullscreen()]

Using this code direct from https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/

```
if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
            docElm.requestFullscreen();
        }
        else if (docElm.msRequestFullscreen) {
            docElm = document.body; //overwrite the element (for IE)
            docElm.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
        else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
        }
        else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        }
        let arTable=[];
        for(let h=0; h<12; h++) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                arTable.push(window.innerHeight);
                },(interval*h));
        }
```

Comment: This question may be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778434/timing-issue-with-detecting-window-innerheight
Is there a statechange type event I can listen for before getting the new window.innerHeight?

Answer (score 0):

No replies on this. My update as the OP is that I used setInterval to check for a change in window.innerHeight every 25ms for 50 iterations then give up, and I've found the property updates in around a handful of iterations on the few systems I've tried.